# Kindle Fire and File Uploads

Tags: html, kindle-fire

I've tried everything I can think of to get the Kindle Fire Browser to accept uploads, no dice. The file picker shows up, but the upload errors. Every once in a blue moon it works, and I can't figure out why. I've tried both HTML5 and normal FORM POST uploads.

Anybody have ideas, or better luck?

Also, the file selector pretends to be HTML5, but then returns 0 for the file size, screwing up any file size display.

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/dbaxD/1/

Comment: Haha. I write an upload component (http://krystalware.com/slickupload), so I like getting on the ball to make sure it works on as many browsers and devices as possible. Usually it's easy to suss out the issue and support a device (or determine that the device doesn't support uploads period), but in this case I'm stumped.

Comment: Does it work if you turn off the silk cloud-acceleration feature?

Comment: @Kevin - Yup, that seems to be exactly it -- uploads don't work with cloud acceleration on. As soon as I flip it off, uploads start working. Do you know of any way to detect cloud acceleration from the browser?

Comment: Sorry, I don't.  I haven't had a chance to do anything with a Fire, and it's been quite some time since I did web programming anyway.

Comment: You could check whether the browser is on a kindle and display a warning along the lines of "uploads don't work with the silk feature on."  Come to think of it, maybe the UA string says whether it's on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like in Silk 2.1 (current version in the FireHD) it now works as expected... i was able to upload test content with the accelerated page loading functions on and off

Answer (score 1):

As long as Jquery Mobile Works Fine With Kindle fire Browser

Check uploadify plugin which can work on Jquery Mobile

http://www.uploadify.com/

Also Check this [Tips](http://www.parorrey.com/blog/jquery-mobile/file-input-field-uploading-using-jquery-mobile-framework-form-submission-with-ajax-disabled/) and [Tutorial](http://devgrow.com/mobile-web-dev-using-jquery-mobile/)

**EDIT** 
Checkout this

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/forms/index.html

And make sure

```
$.mobile.ajaxFormsEnabled = false;
```

And form attribute

```
<form id="form" action="/mobile/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
```

Comment: Uploadify uses flash. I need a raw browser based upload. Flash works for now on Android, but since Adobe has discontinued mobile development of Flash we can't rely on that.

Comment: @Chris Hynes Could u check out http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ in your kindle fire browser

Comment: Still not working. Valums code breaks because the Kindle browser returns file size = 0 for all files, whether or not they have any data.